# Assign long piece of repeated XSLT to variable

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

I'm transforming some XML into a SQL query, using this template. It does what it should do.

```
<xsl:template match="link-info">
  UNION<br/>
  SELECT 
  <xsl:value-of select="//database-info/@name"/>_<xsl:value-of select="key('Tagkey', forwardreferencetag)"/>.term, thesau_term.term,<br/>
  COUNT(<xsl:value-of select="//database-info/@name"/>_<xsl:value-of select="key('Tagkey', forwardreferencetag)"/>.term) AS frequency<br/>
  FROM <xsl:value-of select="//database-info/@name"/>_<xsl:value-of select="key('Tagkey', forwardreferencetag)"/><br/>
  INNER JOIN thesau_term on <xsl:value-of select="//database-info/@name"/>_<xsl:value-of select="key('Tagkey', forwardreferencetag)"/>.term = thesau_term.priref<br/>
  GROUP BY <xsl:value-of select="//database-info/@name"/>_<xsl:value-of select="key('Tagkey', forwardreferencetag)"/>.term, thesau_term.term
  <br/>
</xsl:template>
```

The template generates `SELECT` clauses for a whole bunch of tables. As you can see, table names are constructed from the XML using:

```
<xsl:value-of select="//database-info/@name"/>_<xsl:value-of select="key('Tagkey', forwardreferencetag)"/>
```

which is repeated 5 times. Not DRY. Now, neither `xsl:variable` nor `xsl:param` seem to be intended for making things more readable, something like

```
<xsl:mysnippet name="table_name">
  <xsl:value-of select="//database-info/@name"/>_<xsl:value-of select="key('Tagkey', forwardreferencetag)"/>
</xsl:mysnippet>
```

and then instead of that long clause something like this whenever required.

```
 <xsl:mysnippet name="$table_name" />
```

Is there any way of doing this within XSLT 1.0?

Comment: Interesting question but need an [mcve]. Without an input XML sample and desired results, difficult to understand context of attempted XSLT.

Comment: With XSLT questions please always state your XSLT version. It usually makes a big difference to the answer (and it also means that if you tag the question XSLT 1.0, those of us who have forgotten how to write XSLT 1.0 can ignore the question).

Comment: @Parfait The question is how to make the more readable, not how to fix it. Adding XML and desired result imho would make the question unnecessarily long.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how I might write it in XSLT 3.0

```
<xsl:template match="link-info" expand-text="yes">
  <xsl:variable name="name_tag" select="concat(//database-info/@name,
       key('Tagkey', forwardreferencetag))" as="xs:string"/>
  UNION<br/>
  SELECT {$name_tag}.term, thesau_term.term,<br/>
  COUNT({$name_tag}.term) AS frequency<br/>
  FROM {$name_tag}><br/>
  INNER JOIN thesau_term on {$name_tag}.term = thesau_term.priref<br/>
  GROUP BY {$name_tag}.term, thesau_term.term
  <br/>
</xsl:template>
```

With XSLT 1.0 you can't do the curly-brace expand-text thing, but a variable is still quite an improvement:

```
SELECT <xsl:value-of select="$name_tag"/>.term, thesau_term.term,<br/>
```

Comment: You also have the option of `concat('SELECT ', $table_name, '.term, thesau_term.term,')`

Comment: @Michael Kay Thank you very much, that's just the ticket. I am indeed using XSLT 1.0, I had to omit `as=xs:string" to make it work.

Comment: Ah yes, one forgets (It's been a long time...)